# Reduce Cyclomatic complexity while processing DataRows

Tags: c#, cyclomatic-complexity

I have the following piece of code which checks if a particular DataRow has a column of a particular name and if it is not NULL.

```
private static bool HasValue(DataColumn c, DataRow row)
{
     if (c != null && row != null && row[c.ColumnName] != System.DBNull.Value)
     {
         return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Also I am processing the columns of a datarow and parsing it into corresponding datatypes.

```
foreach (DataColumn c in row.Table.Columns)
{
     switch (c.ColumnName)
     {
     case Constants.Literals.ACTIVATIONDATETIME:
                                if (HasValue(c, row))
                                {
                                    bFound = true; credentialInfo.ActivationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(Convert.ToString(row[c.ColumnName]));
                                }
                                break;
     }
}
```

Visual Studio shows this as cyclomatically complex. Is there any way to reduce the cyclomatic index on this function.

Comment: delete all that and use a proper strongly typed data model. That way there's no need to check if stuff has a certain other stuff with a certain name because you're working with strongly typed stuff rather than stringly typed dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through `row.Table.Columns` to find out if table contains a column, you can do this:

```
var column = row.Table.Columns[Constants.Literals.ACTIVATIONDATETIME];
if(HasValue(column, row))
{
     //column found.
}
```

This eliminates the loop and switch within it and reduces the cyclomatic complexity of your function significantly.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the cyclomatic complexity a *tad* by simply returning the chained AND statements:

```
private static bool HasValue(DataColumn c, DataRow row)
{
    return c != null && row != null && row[c.ColumnName] != DBNull.Value;
}
```